# Handling GetSidIdentifierAuthority function's return value

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am using GetSidIdentifierAuthority function for some operation and it returns me a pointer. After I've done with it, I would like to free this pointer. But, whenever I try to free it, it crushes immediately.

```
PSID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY pSid= NULL;
EXPLICIT_ACCESS *pEa= NULL;
PACL pACL = NULL;
ULONG eaSize = 0;
DWORD dwRes = 0;
//some initialization
dwRes = GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl(pACL, &eaSize, &pEa);
pSid= GetSidIdentifierAuthority(pEa[0].Trustee.ptstrName);
//Here GetLastError returns sucess
LocalFree((HLOCAL)pEa); //This call success
LocalFree((HLOCAL)pACL); //This call success
LocalFree(pSid); //This call crushes
```

In my opinion, since this is a pointer and GetSidIdentifierAuthority already returned, it should be freed by me but i am not able to do it. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetSidIdentifierAuthority

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446655(v=vs.85).aspx

The GetSidIdentifierAuthority function returns a pointer to the SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY structure **in a** specified security identifier (SID).

pSid is simply pointing to memory inside pEa. Since you freed pEa the memory pointed to by pSid is gone freeing pSid will result in a crash.

Do not free pSid in your code, it is not a new block of memory.

Answer (score 1):

> PSID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY WINAPI GetSidIdentifierAuthority(   *In*
>   PSID pSid );

According to the MSDN, `GetSidIdentifierAuthority` function searches and returns a pointer to the `SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY` struct inside the variable-length `SID` structure. It does not allocate any additional memory, so you should not free it result. The memory would be cleared when you deallocate your `SID` structure.